# Get only changes in the database

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a view in the database as below which is ordered by date:

```
date            company_name        share
25.7.2016       Apple               20
25.7.2016       Samsung             50
26.7.2016       Apple               20
26.7.2016       Samsung             50
27.7.2016       Apple               30
27.7.2016       Samsung             40
```

What I need to do is to check if data between two consequent dates are the same. If yes, display only the data of the first date.

In my example, dates 25.7.2016 have the same data as 26.7.2016, while date 26.7.2016 doesn't have the same data as the previous one.

So I need my view to look like:

```
date            company_name        share
25.7.2016       Apple               20
25.7.2016       Samsung             50
27.7.2016       Apple               30
27.7.2016       Samsung             40
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please tag the database being used.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala can we suppose the view is the actual table, and I need a query to return only different records between two consequent dates?

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the window function `lag()` to access the value of the previous row:

```
select date, company_name, share
from (
  select date, company_name, share,
         lag(share) over (partition by company_name order by date) as prev_share
  from sometable
) x
where (prev_share is null or prev_share <> share)
order by date, company_name;
```

The `prev_share is null` is necessary to include the first row of a "group" (=partition) in the result. This could have been done with a default value on the lag() function as well.

You didn't state your DBMS, but the above is standard SQL that works on any [modern DBMS](http://modern-sql.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't mention which database you are working with, I'm giving you a logical solution in pseudo-code:

```
if previous company_name = company_name AND previous share = share
if true then nothing
```